# Postgres + PHP class

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm new to PHP and Postgres.  I was wondering what is the best way to create a class from a database table?

For example, I have a table with columns `ID, First, Last, Middle`

What is the nest approach to have a class Person that has a method, `load_by_id` that will load all properties of the matched row.  This way I can retrieve the properties executing `$person->first` etc. Does this all have to be created manually within the class or is there an automagic approach?

Comment: The general term for this is "database reverse engineering" or "database to model". Might help you find some info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library ?